# How can strings with non-ASCII characters be retrieved with OptParse?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, apsw

I'm using the `OptParse` module to retrieve a string value. [`OptParse` only supports `str` typed strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse-standard-option-types), not `unicode` ones.

So let's say I start my script with:

```
./someScript --some-option ééééé
```

French characters, such as 'é', being typed `str`, trigger `UnicodeDecodeError`s when read in the code:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 99: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I played around a bit with the unicode built-in function, but either I get an error, or the character disappears:

```
>>> unicode('é');
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> unicode('é', errors='ignore');
u''
```

Is there anything I can do to use `OptParse` to retrieve `unicode`/`utf-8` strings?

It seems that the string can be retrieved and printed OK, but then I try to use that string with SQLite (using the APSW module), and it tries to convert to unicode somehow with `cursor.execute("...")`, and then the error occurs.

Here is a sample program that causes the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("--some-option")
(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
print unicode(opts.some_option)
```

Comment: Str objects are just byte stores so if the input is UTF-8, the string will hold the UTF-8 value. Where is the unicode error being thrown?

Comment: I've just tested this on a UTF-8 console and optparse works fine and returns the character to the console. Can you clarify if this error is in your code or in the optparse?

Comment: Depends your program on optparse or you are building from scratch? In that case I would recommend the docopts package instead of the optparse. You will be really really really surprised how easy it parses the cli arguments.

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt: I've narrowed my question a bit thanks to your second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is returned in the console encoding, so based on your updated example, use:

```
print opts.some_option.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

`unicode(opts.some_option)` defaults to using `ascii` as the encoding.

Answer (score 4):

You could decode the arguments before the parser handles them. Taking your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
import os, sys, optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("--some-option")

# Decode the command line arguments to unicode
for i, a in enumerate(sys.argv):
    sys.argv[i] = a.decode('ISO-8859-15')

(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
print type(opts.some_option), opts.some_option
```

This gives the following output:

```
C:\workspace>python file.py --some-option préférer
<type 'unicode'> préférer
```

I've chose the [ISO/IEC 8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) code page, as it seems most appropriate to you. Adapt if needed.

Comment: To avoid to hardcode the encoding you could try to guess it like that : ``locale.getpreferredencoding()`` (import ``locale``).

Comment: By the way, you may need to make it unicode with ``unicode(a.decode("your_encoding_here"))``.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is related to the [following](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding):

> For example, to write Unicode literals including the Euro currency
>   symbol, the ISO-8859-15 encoding can be used, with the Euro symbol
>   having the ordinal value 164. This script will print the value 8364
>   (the Unicode codepoint corresponding to the Euro symbol) and then
>   exit:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

currency = u"€"
print ord(currency)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, optparse

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option(u"--some-option")
(opts, args) = parser.parse_args()
print opts.print_help()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  Were you using python 2 or 3?  I'm running python 2.7.